# How to handle links pointing to non-English website?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, languages, non-english-speakers

I was trying to review the below suggested edit. I thought that I could improve it by replacing the raw URL with a more appropriate display text surrounded by anchor tags. I clicked on the link to find out what it is about but it is a non-English website. I did't know what to do with it or how to phrase a text for the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1607181

Before my mind could process all these, another user had already edited the URL with a simple text of `this`.

I am aware that SO supports only posts in English. I am not sure how to handle URLs that link to non-English websites.

How to handle these type of posts that have links to external non-English websites? What is the appropriate way to deal with them in suggested edit queues?

#### Similar occurrence:

I just came across a similar suggested edit but it is related to non-English content. This one has some text in another language and including the screenshot. User tried to translate the content partially but I can see some of the text like `makro` and `kreditlimit` within the body are still not translated.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1607231

Comment: You can ignore the link (unless it is spam), if the post is in English and is sufficient. If the post is not in English, you can either 1) flag 2) translate the post into English.

Comment: But please don't start translating source code.

Comment: @nhahtdh: If I know the language well, sure I would translate the content. Unfortunately, I don't know either of the languages I have referenced in the suggested edit examples.

Comment: @Bart: Sorry, what do you mean by source code? Are you referring to the usage of non-English variables inside the source code? I usually don't touch source code except for formatting purposes.

Comment: Yes. The `kreditlimit` you refer to is part of the German source code. Don't start changing such things.

Comment: @Bart: Wouldn't this fall under too localized category? I thought that the questions/answers are supposed to be helpful to others in general.

Comment: How is writing your source code in another language too localized? I think it's a bad idea to program in any language other than English (disregarding strings of course), but that does not make your question too localized. I could name my variables `asdf`, and while non-descriptive and certainly not clear when it comes to the code, that does not seem to invalidate the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that case the link was just acting as data for the program to process, so it doesn't really matter what language it was in, **you shouldn't change it**.  Just because that SO requires that posts be in English, doesn't mean that programs are only allowed to process data in English.

In the general case, the usual guidelines for links apply: if the post **would still be fine if the link died**, there's no harm in linking to a site that might help anyone else who speaks the language (though it would probably be polite to note that it's not in English when linking).  If the post **relies on the link**, then it's not a complete post and should be flagged.

---

In your second example, the only non-English is in data and variable names.  While descriptive and comprehensible code makes for a better question, it is not required.  After all, no one would look askance if all the variables were unhelpfully named `a`, `b`, `c`.